# What is Pramolan, is it an Opioid?

Tags: opioids-opiates

What is *Pramolan*? Is Pramolan an *Opioid*?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. I have edited your post and removed the request for alternatives (only your personal doctor should give them), and the question whether they are bad for you. Obviously, at a dosage too high anything is bad for you, so unless you specify usage that part of your question is too broad. Once you specify the usage however, it falls under outclose reason of being personal medical advice, Android is whyI have simply removed that part entirely. If you have any questions regarding a personal medical issue related to drugs, please visit a pharmacist or doctor of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opipramol (the molecule that is being sold under multiple names including Pramolan) [is a nonselective monoamine reputake inhibitor with ATC code N06AA05](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/9417#section=ATC-Code)

Opioids have the [leading ATC number N02A...](https://www.whocc.no/atc_ddd_index/?code=N02A), hence Opipramol is not an opioid.